# Matlab: optimal-distance matching of the elements of two sets

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment

I have two floating-point number vectors which contain the same values up to a small error, but not necessarily sorted in the same way; for instance, `A=rand(10);a=eig(A);b=eig(A+1e-10);` (remember that `eig` outputs eigenvalues in no specified order).

I need to find a permutation `p` that matches the corresponding elements, i.e. `p=mysterious_function(a,b)` such that `norm(a-b(p))` is small.

Is there an existing function that does this in a sane and safe way, or do I really need to roll out my own slow and poorly-error-checked implementation?

I need this only for test purposes for now, it need not be excessively optimized. Notice that the solution which involves sorting both vectors with `sort` fails in case of vectors containing complex equal-modulus arguments, such as the typical output of `eig()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to solve the [linear assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). I haven't tested it myself, but [this piece of code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11609) should help you.

Comment: Seen this, thanks (I wanted to create the tag "assignment problem", but I have not enough reputation). I am now using similar code, but I still had to write some error-prone boilerplate wrapper. I hoped to find something pre-canned; this seemed quite a common problem to my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `sort()` solution you discarded might actually work for you; The criteria you have defined `minimize norm(a-b)` is, by definition, considering the modulus (absolute value) of the complex number: `norm(a-b) == sqrt(sum(abs(a-b).^2))`

And as you know, `SORT` orders complex numbers based on their absolute value: `sort(a)` is equivalent to `sort(abs(a))` for complex input.

```
%# sort by complex-magnitude
[sort(a) sort(b)]
```

As long as the same order is applied to both, you might as well try lexicographic ordering (sort by real part, if equal, then sort by imaginary part):

```
%# lexicographic sort order
[~,ordA] = sortrows([real(a) imag(a)],[1 2]);
[~,ordB] = sortrows([real(b) imag(b)],[1 2]);
[b(ordB) a(ordA)]
```

---

If you are too lazy to implement the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) that [@AnthonyLabarre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955460/matlab-optimal-distance-matching-of-the-elements-of-two-sets/6955518#6955518) suggested, go for brute-forcing:

```
A = rand(5);
a = eig(A);
b = eig(A+1e-10);

bb = perms(b);                                       %# all permutations of b
nrm = sqrt( sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus, a,bb')).^2) );    %'
[~,idx] = min(nrm);                                  %# argmin norm(a-bb(i,:))
[bb(idx,:)' a]
```

---

Beside the fact that eigenvalues returned by EIG are not guaranteed to be sorted, there is another difficulty you have to deal with if you to match eigenvectors as well: they are not unique in the sense that if `v` is an eigenvector, then `k*v` is also one, especially for `k=-1`. Usually you would enforce a sign convention like: multiply by -/+1 so that the largest element in each vector have a positive sign.

Comment: The sort-based solution would work if the eigenvalues were computed exactly. If the real eigenvalues are 1i, 1 and -1, and `a` contains `[0.99;-1.01;1i]` while `b` contains `[1.01;-0.99;1i]`, then all sort-based solutions are bound to fail. In fact, I guess that all solutions that work separately on  `a` and `b` to derive a common order are bound to fail.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: good counter-example (though lexicographic ordering works for it)... I guess solving the assignment problem is the way to go :)